# php if (isset($_POST['tables'])) syntax

Tags: php, syntax

I've been trying to fix this problem forever now and its bugging me. the code is to display a table selected from the dropbox which works fine..but when i put it in with my layout/template it throws an error & i have no idea why!

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" >
<meta name="description" content="" >
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>SNYSB Archive</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" >
<!-- Location of javascript. -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js" ></script>
</head>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <!-- KEEP THIS BIT [ITS FORMATTING] --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end #header -->
    <div id="menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="Hpage.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
    <div id="page">
    <div id="page-bgtop">
    <div id="page-bgbtm">
    <div id="content">
            <div class="post">
            <div class="post-bgtop">
            <div class="post-bgbtm">
<h1 class="title">PUT HEADING HERE!</h1>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p class="Body">
<?php
$dbname = 'snysbarchive';
$conn= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw');
if (!$conn) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn))
{
?>
    <form method="post" action="new 2.php">
    <select name="tables">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    ?>    
    <?php
        echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Show">
</form>
<?php
//mysql_free_result($result);
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['tables']))
{
    $tbl=$_POST['tables'];
    //echo $_POST['tables']."<br />";
    $query="SELECT * from $tbl";
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    echo $query;
    if ($res)
    {
    ?>
    <table border="1">
    <?php
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";        
            echo "</tr>";
        } ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
</div>
</div>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #content -->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
                    <p>Welcome to SNYSBs archive!
                       </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>SNYSB</h2>
                    <p>
            <a href="Contact.php">Contact Us!</a>
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end #sidebar -->
        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #page -->
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008 Sitename.com. All rights reserved. Design by <a href="http://www.freecsstemplates.org/">Free CSS Templates</a>.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end #footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Just pasted the entire page's code from the original with my template at the start and bottom)

This is the line it doesnt like:

```
if (isset($_POST['tables']))
```

Thanks

Edit: New error message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in FILENAME on line 128

Comment: It's useful to post the errors you're trying to troubleshoot, especially given that there are several syntax errors alone in the above code.

Comment: The error is apparently the line with if (isset($_POST['tables']))
The thing i dont understand is that the code works perfectly fine..but when ive added format code above and below this section its throwing up the error

Comment: Now you are missing one closing bracket at the end I believe :)

Comment: Thanks yep sorted :) its always a bracket!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're seeing is likely because $_POST doesn't have a key called 'tables'.

```
echo"<form method="post" action="show_tabs.php">";
echo"<select name="tables">";
```

both produce errors when I run them. Notice the syntax highlighting color changes on SO, indicating that not all is being interpreted as a string literal. You need to either escape the inner quotes or switch the outer ones to single quotes:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="show_tabs.php">';
echo '<select name="tables">';
```

or

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"show_tabs.php\">";
echo "<select name=\"tables\">";
```

The same goes for

```
echo"<input type="submit" value="Show">";
...
echo"<table border="1">";
```

Also,

```
if ($res)
}
```

should read

```
if ($res)
{
```

Furthermore, you have an error in your usage of the mysql_* functions. I can see you're selecting your db only after having run a query, and I don't see a call to `mysql_connect`. The order is connect, select_db, query, fetch, free, close as seen in http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php

---

(After above code was updated)
Wrapping the whole thing in a heredoc is clearly the cause, and is very unnecessary. Simply use php open and closing tags to switch between text and code. For instance instead of

```
echo <<< TEMPLATE
<h1 class="title">PUT HEADING HERE!</h1>
<div class="entry">
<p class="Body">
```

use

```
?>
<h1 class="title">PUT HEADING HERE!</h1>
<div class="entry">
<p class="Body">
<?php
```

Code inside of a heredoc doesn't get executed (although variables are substituted), so none of the code from `<<< TEMPLATE` to `TEMPLATE;` is being run. Only variables should go inside a heredoc.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions but the same error displays..not sure why the code works on the page but when i add it to my template it messes up...

Comment: Thanks changed the bracket error - clerical typo when copying the working code to the template!

Comment: the mysql connect is included at the top of the page..it wasnt included in the question as it wasnt part of the problem

Comment: After making the changes mentioned, `php -l` doesn't show any syntax errors in the code :/

Comment: I've made all of the changes suggested and it still throws the same error..sorry about this!

Comment: Thanks, i've got rid of the heredoc bits & put the template html straight on the page with the problem code and now it doesnt seem to like the end..Really sorry about these problems but i've been staring at it for hours!!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is actually 3 lines earlier;

```
echo"<input type="submit" value="Show">";
```

It should probably use single quotes as to not conflict with the double ones inside the string;

```
echo '<input type="submit" value="Show">';
```

and another few lines;

```
echo"<form method="post" action="show_tabs.php">";
...
echo"<table border="1">";
```

that should be fixed in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this...

```
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['tables']))
```